# How to change the alpha channel of an existing background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, alpha, uicolor

I have a `UITextField` which has an `rgb` already applied to its background color. I'm trying to set the alpha of the background color. How can I set the alpha without reinserting the whole `rgb` color in `Objective-c`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
CGFloat newAlpha = 0.7;
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha(self.yourTextField.layer.backgroundColor, newAlpha);
[self.yourTextField.layer setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Or if you already know the color and just want the current alpha:

```
CGFloat alpha = CGColorGetAlpha(self.yourTextField.layer.backgroundColor); //Get current alpha       
self.yourTextField.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:alpha].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
UIColor *color = ...;
color = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 or 4:

```
let color: UIColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```